# Weird behaviour of bif:st_intersects in virtuoso sparql

Tags: sparql, rdf, geospatial, virtuoso

Using the latest stable release: Virtuoso version 07.20.3215 on Linux (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu).

My initial SPARQL query on a custom N3 serialized RDF dataset is:

```
select (?s as ?addr), 
       ?geo, 
       (bif:st_distance (?geo, bif:st_point(51.3, 12.3)) as ?dist)
where 
{
  ?s <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#asWKT> ?geo .
  ?s <http://location/class> "place" .
  ?s <http://location/type> "house" . 
}
```

and it gives desired result:

```html
<table class="sparql" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>addr</th>
    <th>geo</th>
    <th>dist</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="addr1">addr1</a></td>
    <td>"POINT(51.345624 12.3918959)"^^&lt;http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/virtrdf#Geometry&gt;</td>
    <td>11.3504</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Though when I add a `FILTER` statement for `bif:st_intersects`, using the following query:

```
select (?s as ?addr), 
       ?geo, 
       (bif:st_distance (?geo, bif:st_point(51.3, 12.3)) as ?dist)
where 
{
  ?s <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#asWKT> ?geo .
  ?s <http://location/class> "place" .
  ?s <http://location/type> "house" .
  FILTER (bif:st_intersects (?geo, bif:st_point (51.3, 12.3), 100)) 
}
```

It gives me an error message saying `No table rdf_obj`

```
Virtuoso S0002 Error SQ200: No table rdf_obj

SPARQL query:
define sql:big-data-const 0 
#output-format:text/html
define sql:signal-void-variables 1 define input:default-graph-uri <http://localhost:8890/custom1> select (?s as ?addr), ?geo, (bif:st_distance (?geo, bif:st_point(51.3, 12.3)) as ?dist)
where 
{
  ?s <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#asWKT> ?geo .
  ?s <http://location/class> "place" .
  ?s <http://location/type> "house" .
  FILTER (bif:st_intersects (?geo, bif:st_point (51.3, 12.3), 100)) 
}
```

Why is this happening and is there any work around for this ?

Comment: You don't mention your Virtuoso version so I would first suggest an upgrade to the latest version. A quick search brings up many related issues which are also fairly new. https://www.google.gr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Virtuoso+S0002+Error+SQ200%3A+No+table+rdf_obj You should switch to the Virtuoso Mailing List.

Comment: it's the latest stable release: Virtuoso version 07.20.3215 on Linux (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)

Comment: i also switched to the development branch and its still giving me the same error :(

Comment: Try experimenting with the parameters passed to the `bif` functions. Maybe it' s a combination of values that bring out a bug. For example, try changing the tolerance factor(100) in `bif:st_intersects`. Try to reformat your query to use another of the geometric functions(`st_may_intersect` or `st_within`). Try with different RDF sample data. In the end you will get a clearer view of what might be wrong. Remember to post your question on the Virtuoso Mailing List

Comment: Virtuoso-specific issues are often better and faster addressed via Virtuoso-specific resources -- [mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), [GitHub issues](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/), [public OpenLink support forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php), [confidential OpenLink support case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp)… ObDisclaimer: I work for [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), producer of Virtuoso.

Comment: @ViNi89 , less tolerance should cause empty table in result. The bug here says the table doesn't exist. That's what making this bug weird for me.

Comment: @TallTed, Thanks for replying and creating such a great tool. I'll surely raise an issue on github :)